Right aligning text (for Hebrew)?
Is there any way to right-align (flush right)  paragraphs in Mi Yodeya? Specifically for Hebrew.
I.e. I wish to be able to produce content that looks like this:

Rather than this:

Related but not the same (these are about basic right-to-left formatting, not alignment):
Right to Left formatting for Hebrew
Integrated virtual keyboards for posts and chat

This question is similar to: Right to Left formatting for Hebrew. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@robev clearly different. I already mentioned that in my question as different.

When you originally posted it you weren't clear you were talking about floating the paragraph to the right :)

@robev you can gain atonement for us both if you upvote :) ;) :P

Whelp, I really thought that there would be at least ONE other person in 50 views that also saw this as a good idea lol
